# PHP: Replace only complete Strings - Not Parts?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I want to replace only complete strings with another string. But the problem is that `str_ireplace()` is looking for contains...

For example:

```
str_ireplace('RU', 'RUS', $array[$i]);
```

Input:

> Trillion God Of Strusction rus Luxe

Output:

> Trillion God Of StRUSction RUS Luxe

What I want is this:

> Trillion God Of Strusction RUS Luxe

How can I do that? - I didnt't find a method for that... :/

Greetings

Comment: `preg_replace('/\bRU\b/i', 'RUS', $array[$i]);`

Comment: And how can I do that with an array of replacements I want to exchange with "" (nothing/delete);

Comment: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) accepts array of patterns and corresponding replacement string array.

Comment: So I must say if I also want only to get the exactly word and ignore case:
preg_replace('/\b$pattern\b/i', 'RUS', $array[$i]);

Comment: Variables aren't variables in single quotes. Use double quotes, or concatenate. Is `$pattern` an array?

Comment: If you have a more specific question, feel free to update it - and it will most likely be reopened.